# Is there a way to use SKSpriteNode positional audio as an activatable effect on AVEngine?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avaudioengine

I am experimenting with positional audio as an audio effect. So far I built a UI which allows to position audio sources a grid which gives a positional audio experience due to the SKAudioNode.isPositional property.

I am now trying to pack this into an activatable effect which you can turn on and off without resetting the playback of the sources. So far I am thinking of using the AVAudioEngine to attach and detach the AVAudioEnvironmentNode to achieve this effect. So far this caused the stopping of the playback of the sources (which I also could not resume by attaching the environment node afterwards).

This is the detach of the evironmentNode

```
for node in self.scene!.audioEngine.attachedNodes {
    if node.className == "AVAudioEnvironmentNode" {
         self.environmentNode = node as? AVAudioEnvironmentNode
              self.scene!.audioEngine.detach(node)
    }
}
```

And this is the attach of the environmentNode afterwards

```
do {
   self.scene!.audioEngine.attach(environmentNode)
        try self.scene!.audioEngine.start()
}catch {
   print("Error: CANT START AUDIO ENGINE")
}
```

Therefore, this question arised which I could not answer myself:

1. During my research I saw that AVAudioEngine appears not to be able to reconnect AudioNodes without resetting the playback. Is there a way to bypass this limitation in Swift?

Comment: "experimenting with positional audio as an chain able effect"  What is a chain able effect?  It doesn't sound like an English expression.

Comment: @ElTomato adjusted it to "audio effect". My goal is to have a track playing where I can turn on the audio effect and turn it off, without interrupting the playback.